# Reading random text file in R

Tags: r, dataset

I have about 500 text documents stored in a directory.  I want to randomly select one to read in the contents (this process will be repeated several times).  The names of the files are not sequential.  By this I mean they are not named something like 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt,...   The names are basically random characters.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, select one file randomly from the current directory:

```
file <- sample(list.files(), 1)
```

Then do whatever you want  with it, e.g. read all lines:

```
readLines(file)
```

If you want to repeat this several times, you could do it in one step:

```
readLines(sample(list.files(), 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Do a list.files and then access each file by its index.

```
 lisfil <- list.files("E:\\Data") #Replace E:\\Data with your directory name
 lenlisfil <- length(lisfil)
 for (i in 1:lenlisfil) {
    #Do something to the current file such as:
    print(lisfil[i])
 }
```

Comment: You need to shuffle `listfil` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @chl: I assumed that getting the filenames into a variable was his main question.

Comment: Yes, I just re-read the question and it makes sense as filenames are assumed to follow no particular order.